# Flutter/Dart Null Safety Migration

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am trying to migrate my Flutter/Dart project to use null safety. I have updated all of my dependencies and changed the sdk to use ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0". However, when I try to use the migration tool I get the following error:

[image]

When I look at my flutter and dart versions everything seems fine. I may be looking at it wrong, but below is the output from flutter doctor and brew info dart:

```
% flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor -- 
android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
 % brew info dart
dart-lang/dart/dart: stable 2.12.4, HEAD
The Dart SDK
https://dart.dev
Conflicts with:
  dart-beta (because dart-beta ships the same binaries)
/usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.9.3 (509 files, 523.7MB) *
  Built from source on 2020-09-14 at 16:52:16
From: https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/blob/HEAD/dart.rb
==> Options
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Please note the path to the Dart SDK:
  /usr/local/opt/dart/libexec
```

I'm suspecting that maybe I don't have the latest dart sdk like I believe I do. If that's the case then how do I upgrade without breaking anything?

UPDATE:

It appears I am using the latest version of dart. Going into the settings in Android Studio I can see it is pointing at the dart sdk that ships with flutter:

[image]

Comment: That's an ancient dart, and even if you migrated your code with the totally-absent dart migrate, it wouldn't be able to compile or run the migrated code!  Best bet is to remove your brew dart version, and use the version of dart automatically downloaded by a flutter upgrade.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz check my update. I think I had an older version of the dart sdk installed somewhere else. My project is actually looking at the version that ships with flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run "flutter upgrade" in your terminal?